# Удаления записей в связанных таблицах MySQL v5.7

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

Необходимо удалить записи из `url_xml` где `url_xml.teg = '2'`, а также удалить связанную с ней запись из `url`, записей в таблицах около 5 миллионов

В результате нужно удалить записи из `url` с `id (1 - 2)`, и записи из `url_xml` с `id (1 - 6 и 10)`

Таблица (url) :

```
CREATE TABLE `url` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `reg` tinyint(4),
  `teg` tinyint(4),
  `url` tinyint(4),
  `zip` tinytext,
  `date` datetime,
  `size` bigint(20),
  `status` tinyint(1),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Пример данных в (url):

```
id  reg     teg     url     zip                         date                    size        status
==================================================================================================
1   6       0       0       20140101002014020100012     2014-05-13 11:03:09     44573       1
2   6       0       0       20140109002014011000001     2014-03-20 15:41:52     1584        1
3   6       0       0       20140110002014011100001     2014-03-20 18:26:52     6363        1
4   6       0       0       20140113002014011400001     2014-03-21 00:41:52     1733        1
5   6       0       0       20140114002014011500001     2014-03-21 04:14:52     4787        1
6   6       0       0       20140115002014011600001     2014-03-21 08:05:52     1773        1
7   6       0       0       20140201002014030100017     2014-05-13 11:24:59     507311      1
```

Таблица (url_xml) :

```
CREATE TABLE `url_xml` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `xml` tinytext,
  `teg` tinyint(4),
  `id_zip` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `url_xml` FOREIGN KEY (`id_zip`) REFERENCES `url` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Пример данных в (url_xml):

```
id  xml                             teg     id_zip
==================================================
1   44034810007061400000112579      2       1
2   44037310011911400000115123      2       1
3   44037310011911400000220799      2       1
4   44014810000201400000122852      3       1
5   44034810007061400000233390      3       1
6   44037310011911400000335696      5       1
7   44037310011911400000220799      3       2
8   44014810000201400000122852      3       4
9   44034810007061400000233390      3       5
10  44037310011911400000335696      2       2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете попробовать отключить проверку внешних ключей:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; 
/*тут должна быть команда на удаление данных*/
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Пересоздайте внешний ключ с опцией ON DELETE CASCADE:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE `url_xml` DROP FOREIGN KEY `url_xml`;
   ALTER TABLE `url_xml`
     ADD CONSTRAINT `url_xml`
         FOREIGN KEY (`id_zip`) REFERENCES `url` (`id`)
         ON DELETE CASCADE;
   ```
2. Спокойно удаляйте записи из таблицы `url`:

   ```
   DELETE FROM url
    WHERE id IN( SELECT id_zip FROM url_xml WHERE teg=2 );
   ```

С опцией ON DELETE CASCADE при удалении записи из родительской таблицы (url) все записи из дочерней таблици (url_xml) удалятся автоматически.